Rstudio: binary list - check probability of previous value changed (or remained the same)
I am new to R.
The vector I am analyzing is a list of items (a,a,b,a,b,b,b,a etc.).
I need to count probability of a (previous element) becoming b (next element), a becoming a, b becoming a and b becoming b.
4 results need to create a matrix.
Can you please advise how to do it?
I read about str_detect function, duplicate_count,  str_count function, but I do not know how may I apply it for my task.
Thank you in advance for help and reply!

I'll use the following vector as an example:
(seed <- sample(.Machine$integer.max, 1))
#> [1] 2041751758
set.seed(seed) # for reproducibility

(x <- sample(c("a", "b"), 10, TRUE))
#>  [1] "b" "b" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "a" "a"

The easiest way is to use table:
table(data.frame(from = x[-length(x)], to = x[-1]))
#>     to
#> from a b
#>    a 3 1
#>    b 2 3

To do the same thing manually, use matrix, tabulate, and Boolean arithmetic. First, encode the four possibilities as integers. For a vectorized solution, x[-length(x)] will be the "from" value in each transition, and x[-1] will be the "to" value. If the "from" value is "a", add 0. If it is "b" add 1. If the "to" value is "a" add 0. If it is "b", add 2. Add 1 to each result to get the values between 1 and 4.
tabulate counts the number of each integer value in a vector. There are four possibilities, so set tabulate's nbins argument to 4L.
Finally, put the results of tabulate in a matrix with 2 rows and 2 columns and set the names as desired. I set mine so that "a->" means a transition started with "a", and "->a" means the transition ended with "a".
matrix(tabulate((x[-length(x)] == "b") + 2L*(x[-1] == "b") + 1L, 4L),
       2, 2, 0, list(c("a->", "b->"), c("->a", "->b")))
#>     ->a ->b
#> a->   3   1
#> b->   2   3

Compare the performance of the two approaches with a larger vector:
x <- sample(c("a", "b"), 1e6, TRUE)

trans1 <- function(x) table(data.frame(from = x[-length(x)], to = x[-1]))

trans2 <- function(x) {
  x <- x == "b"
  matrix(tabulate(x[-length(x)] + 2L*x[-1] + 1L, 4L),
         2, 2, 0, list(c("a->", "b->"), c("->a", "->b")))
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  table = trans1(x),
  tabulate = trans2(x)
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>      expr     min      lq      mean   median        uq      max neval cld
#>     table 84.2272 88.4737 102.27207 91.48075 123.30125 133.5508   100  a 
#>  tabulate 25.1709 26.7004  32.58225 27.66895  30.02525  68.6166   100   b


Thank you very much jblood94, that's exactly what I was looking for!
